No module named 'torch' when I run my code
I have tried to install PyTorch using pip install torch command. When, however, I am trying to run some Python code I am receiving the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

When I am checking the packages with pip list the torch is missing. How, can I do the installation properly and enforce it in the proper environment?

You said "I have installed PyTorch using pip install torch", and you also said "When I am checking the packages with pip list the torch is missing".  I don't see how both of those can be true.  What happens, exactly, when you run pip install torch?

Oh I am receiving the following error:
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'TBB'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

You should not just run pip install torch, go to this link Start Locally | PyTorch and pick the correct options, then copy the install command.

Yes that worked indeed. Is there an explanation for that or a documentation?

Also, is there a way to do the same for torchvision and install specific version?
